# Spark dont flush window with append mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have latest version spark, pyspark.

I use window aggregation + watermark and output to console with mode APPEND. Read from kafka topic.

Watermark = windows = 30 seconds

```
 .withWatermark("dt", "30 seconds")
 .groupBy("dt", "30 seconds"))
```

Trigger every 10 seconds

```
console = sel 
    .writeStream 
    .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds') 
    .format("console") 
    .outputMode("append")
    .option("truncate", "false") 
    .start()
```

What is problem? I send 100 messages ~every 1 second and after 30 second i take `RIGHT result` get 13 messages before 10:40:30 (other words i send=get 13 messages in this windows **all right**)

[image]

My soft keeps sending messages to 100. I'm waiting next 30 second and happing nothing.
What you see in the picture does not change.

**Question:**
Why doesn't Spark handle the next windows?
You may ask what does it have to do with Flush?

I've found experimentally that after a some minute I should send another message and then Spark will close the **previous window**.

[image]

Is it bug? Or what? Why dont flush preview window?

Simple situation here:
[image]

Update 1:
After researching we clarified and understood what is specific problem, we decided to create a new more precise question:
[Spark last window dont flush in append mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75904932/spark-last-window-dont-flush-in-append-mode)

Comment: Duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75904932/spark-last-window-dont-flush-in-append-mode

Comment: Yes, we clarified and understood what it was, we decided to create a new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75904932/spark-last-window-dont-flush-in-append-mode