# Spark last window dont flush in append mode

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

The problem is very simple, when you use TUMBLING **window** with **append mode**, then the window is closed **only when the next message arrives** (+watermark logic).

In the current implementation, if you stop incoming streaming data, the last window will NEVER close and we LOSE the last window data.

How can we force the last window to close\flush if new data stops incoming?

**Business situation:**

Worked correctly and new messages stop incoming and next message come in 5 hours  later and the client will get the message after 5 hours instead of the 10 seconds delay of window.

[image]

Spark v3.3.2 Code of problem:

```
kafka_stream_df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", KAFKA_BROKER) \
    .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC) \
    .option("includeHeaders", "true") \
    .load()

sel = (kafka_stream_df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
       .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), json_schema).alias("data"))
       .select("data.*")
       .withWatermark("dt", "1 seconds")
       .groupBy(window("dt", "10 seconds"))
       .agg(sum("price"))
      )




console = sel \
    .writeStream \
    .trigger(processingTime='10 seconds') \
    .format("console") \
    .outputMode("append")\
    .start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt find solution with watermarking but One way to resolve this is to remove watermarking and apply filter. That way you get close to watermarking behavior via filter and not have the issue.

```
sel = (kafka_stream_df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
       .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), json_schema).alias("data"))
       .select("data.*")
       .filter("dt" > DateTime.now - Interval("5 minutes") && "dt" < DateTime.now + Interval("5 minutes"))
       .groupBy(window("dt", "10 seconds"))
       .agg(sum("price"))
      )
```

Comment: Hi. Nice try, but it doesn't work because you cant set append mode without watermark , will be exception on start

Comment: oh ya .may be you can use update mode and use suitable aggregation downstream ?